# Phonegap multiple form calculate on single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I am having problem with creating tool for my app as I have about 50 input fields. i have created a single html5 file in dreamweaver with phonegap build file is rendering on real device and emulator properly.
I have to do calculation from user input and display on the result page which is in same html5 file.
Problem is how do i do it i have created a java code for same but JAVASCRIPT code is new to me can any one tell me how do i get data out of input box and put data in respective div??

any tutorial will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JAVASCRIPT you can get by `input id or name`. best choice is `Id`.

Get value from input `document.getElementById('IdValue').value;`

Assign value to HTML Element `document.getElementById('IdValue').value = "new value"`

Using input name

Get value from input `document.getElementsByName('inputName').value`

Assign value to HTML Element `document.getElementsByName('inputName').value = "new value"`

Or

You can use JQuery. In JQuery selector is using for getting and setting value

For getting value - `$('selector').val()`
For setting value - `$('selector').val('new value')`

More about [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through all the input fields using jquery and append it to div

```
var test="";
$('input[type=text], textarea').each(function() {
    alert($(this).val())
            test+=$(this).val();
});

// your div
$('#divid').append(test);
```